# ExpressJS: Mongoose query on ISO DATE based on todays date yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have date something like this

```
"createdAt": "ISODate('2021-07-07T06:41:46.000Z')"
```

I have written below mongoose query to fetch records for today. But below query fetched empty.

```
let meeting = await Meeting.find({
     createdAt :  {$lt: new Date().toISOString(),$gte: new Date().toISOString()}
});
```

I have tried below one more way with static date, it worked. I want to fetch data on dynamic todays date.

```
let meeting = await Meeting.find({ 
  createdAt : {
  '$eq': new Date('2021-07-07T06:41:46.000Z')
   }
});
```

Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm assuming the type of "createdAt" field is `Date` in Mongoose schema (you should convert to Date if it wasn't the case).*

#### Logic

When you want to filter documents on a specific day, you can use the condition:

`0:00 the day <= createdAt <  0:00 the following day`

For example, to filter meetings on 07/07/2021, the condition will be:

`0:00 07/07/2021 <= createdAt < 0:00 08/07/2021`

#### Coding

With that logic in mind, the code is pretty straightforward:

```
let today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0); // set to 0:00

let tomorrow = new Date(today)
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)

let meeting = await Meeting.find({
     createdAt :  {$gte: today, $lt: tomorrow}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with date/time values then I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. Could be this one:

```
let meeting = await Meeting.find({
   createdAt :  {
     $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate(), 
     $lte: moment().endOf('day').toDate()
   }
});
```